# Determining if the player is inside or outside of the camera view Godot

Tags: canvas, camera, viewport, godot, gdscript

Using GDScript with the Godot camera. I have a Camera2D object to handle the viewport transforms.

I wish to have the camera move, adjust to screen resolution and zoom in and out. I want to make sure that when the camera is zoomed out that they could not move outside of the camera's perspective.

The player is also a KinematicBody2D object. One thing I was considering what have the player testMove() and determine if their new location would be enclosed by the rectangle that the Camera2D produces.

Answer (score 8):

Just add a [VisibilityNotifier](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_visibilitynotifier.html) to your player scene and call its `is_on_screen` method to check if the bounding box of the notifier is visible on the screen. Adjust the bounding box (rect) of the VisibilityNotifier to fit the size of the player.

Comment: I know this has been a long time since this answer, but since it came up in my search results, I think it's worth saying that since Godot 4.x the VisibilityNotifier has been renamed VisibleOnScreenNotifier3D : https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_visibleonscreennotifier3d.html.